# How to control the memory usage of Mongo DB in windows?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I am using Mongo DB 2.6, Now I have upgrade my Mongo DB to 3.2 version. Now it is using lot of RAM size. Please someone explain me what is

1. mongod --inMemorySizeGB
2. mongod --WiredTigerCacheSizeGB

and how can I assign the value. when I try to assign the value I got the error like

```
Memory: { engineConfig: { inMemorySizeGB: 12 } } } }
2016-03-28T08:40:16.856+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed
errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port
) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2016-03-28T08:40:16.856+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets
 during startup.
2016-03-28T08:40:16.857+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

I need to control the memory usage of Mongo DB, Is there any way for this?

Answer (score 1):

you have to make changes to mongod.config file if you dont have sharded replicated cluster

```
storage:
  engine: inMemory
  inMemory:
    engineConfig:
      inMemorySizeGB: 140
      statisticsLogDelaySecs: 0
```

REF:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/